# Overlay the theoretical normal distribution on my real data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some charts that plot the log normal-ish distribution of some revenue data. I wanted to overlay as a layer/background the theoretical normal distribution just to highlight any skew or difference between my log normal attempt at making the distribution normal and the actual normal distribution. Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

f <- function(x) {
   y <- diamonds$price[diamonds$cut == x]
   paste(seq(-3, 3), scales::dollar(round(mean(y) + seq(-3, 3) * sd(y))), sep = "\n")
}

breaks <- as.vector(sapply(levels(diamonds$cut), f))

diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    mutate(z = scale(price) + 3 + 1000 * as.numeric(cut)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(z)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = z - 2, y = 1), alpha = 0) +
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks =  as.vector(sapply(1:5 * 1000, "+", 0:6)), 
                       labels = breaks) +
    facet_wrap(vars(cut), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6))
```

Looks like:
[image]

In this case diamonds$price is visually not log normal. Is there a way I can overlay the theoretical normal distribution over each chartlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a second dataframe which is the (shifted) normal densities at each cut, and then add it on with a `geom_line`. The `crossing` function is from the `tidyr` package and creates a cross join between the two component dataframes:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f <- function(x) {
  y <- diamonds$price[diamonds$cut == x]
  paste(seq(-3, 3), scales::dollar(round(mean(y) + seq(-3, 3) * sd(y))), sep = "\n")
}

breaks <- as.vector(sapply(levels(diamonds$cut), f))

x <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 1000)

shifted_densities <- data.frame(
  cut = levels(diamonds$cut),
  mean = seq(1000, 5000, length.out = 5) + 3) %>% # group means based on your breaks
  crossing(
    data.frame(x = x, 
               p = dnorm(x))) %>%
  mutate(x = x + mean) # shift everything over to the right center

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(z = scale(price) + 3 + 1000 * as.numeric(cut)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(z)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z - 2, y = 1), alpha = 0) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =  as.vector(sapply(1:5 * 1000, "+", 0:6)), 
                     labels = breaks) +
  facet_wrap(vars(cut), scales = "free_x") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6)) +
  geom_line(aes(x, p), data = shifted_densities, col = "red")
```

[image]